# Display all data and count from each row from other table as well

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to display the data from table `assignee` and the count for `task_assignee` against each id of the table `assignee`

**Tables**

```
assignee
id | name
1    Assignee 1
2    Assignee 2


task_assignee
id | task_id | assignee_id
1       1          1
```

I want here to display all the assignees from `assignee` table and the count from `task_assignee` table against each assignee

**Desired results**

```
name        |   count
Assignee 1      1
Assignee 2      0
```

I have tried this query

```
SELECT  p.name,
    (
    SELECT  COUNT(*)
    FROM    task_assignee v
    WHERE   v.assignee_id = p.id
    )
FROM    assignee
```

But it shows me the syntax error

> ## 1054 - Unknown column 'p.id' in 'field list'

Comment: Just missed the alias in the from clause of the outer query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use left join and count

```
SELECT  p.name, COUNT(task_id)
FROM   assignee p left join task_assignee v
on     p.id=v.assignee_id
```

in your query you missed alis of table

```
SELECT  p.name,
    (
    SELECT  COUNT(*)
    FROM    task_assignee v
    WHERE   v.assignee_id = p.id
    ) as cnt
FROM    assignee p
```

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE     p.id=v.assignee_id LIMIT 0, 25' at line 3

Comment: Hmm, Working now. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
;With AssigneeCount as (
Select assignee_id,Count(*) count 
From task_assignee
Group By assignee_id) 
Select a.name,ISNULL(ac.count,0) count 
    from assignee a 
      Left Join AssigneeCount ac on a.id = ac.assignee_id
```